# Defining dependent variables in pyomo python

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm trying to solve an assignment problem in pyomo. The model is nonlinear, which is written as a Concrete model. The code written is as follows:

```
from __future__ import division
from pyomo.environ import *
import random
import math

import numpy as np

numberOfPoints = 100
numberOfCentroids = 20
tau = 1
model = ConcreteModel()

model.set_I = range(1, numberOfPoints)
model.set_J = range(1, numberOfCentroids)

model.x = Var(model.set_I, model.set_J, domain=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, 1))


def exp_qj(model, j):
    qj = sum(model.x[i, j] for i in model.set_I)


def exp_q(model):
    model.q = sum(qj[j] for j in model.set_J) / model.numberOfCentroids


def obj_expression(model):
    return sum((model.qj[j] - model.q) ** 2 for j in model.set_J) / (model.numberOfCentroids - 1)


model.OBJ = Objective(rule=obj_expression)


def constraint_1(model, i):
    sum(model.x[i, j] for j in model.set_J) == 1


def constraint_2(model, j):
    sum(model.x[i, j] for i in model.set_I) >= 1


def exp_dj(model, j):
    model.dj = sum(model.d[i, j] for i in model.set_I)


def constraint_3(model, j):
    sum(model.x[i, j] for i in model.set_I) <= model.dj / model.numberOfCentroids * (1 - model.tau)


model.pprint()
```

The decision variable is Xij, but qj is also a variable that depends on Xij. qj is used for the definition of the objective function.The commands used for solving the model have not been added yet, but when I try to print the model with model.pprint (), an error occurs as below:

AttributeError: 'ConcreteModel' object has no attribute 'qj'

I wanted to add qj to the model, but this is neither a parameter nor a decision variable. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is a variable in your model, you need to define it as such just like you are doing for `model.x`.  Also, I would make sets `I` and `J` pyomo Sets.  Not required, but your pprint will look much more accurate.

Comment: Thank you so much AirSquid. Now it works and the model is correct but I was using the glpk solver and since the model is quadratic it cannot be solved with this solver. Solvers such as ipopt and BONMIN have been suggested, but I could not install them. It is written that they can be installed using Anaconda, but there was some problems.